# How to map input text, radio, checkbox data when added from Froala editor?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, froala

I am implementing [Froala](https://froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/docs/framework-plugins/react/) editor. Using this user can create forms and add text fields, radio button etc...
As per my requirement User creates a form and send to candidate to fill up and submit the respective form. But I am unable to fetch data which has been entered via candidate in React.js !!

Here is an image of editor

[image: Editor]

Here is an image of demo offer letter

[image: demo offer letter]

How this will look !

Here is the code for viewing section,

```
<div className="mt-20">
  <div
    dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
      __html: content,
    }}
  />
</div>
```

Thanks in advance

I tried with react-froala-wysiwyg package and its component i.e.,
FroalaEditorView which allows to view the editor data in a formatted way but that doesn't catch the change in multiple text box or radio buttons, etc...